# Ionic Share feature not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic-cli

I've been using Ionic for a while, including the "ionic share" command from the CLI.

However, recently, that command fails with:

```
$ ionic share

Invalid command (CLI v2.2.2)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.3
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3 Build version 8E16
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the Ionic CLI doesn't recognize the `ionic share` command, though their documentation hasn't updated this information.

However, you can now share your app from your ionic.io account:

`Dashboard > Settings icon next to the app you want to share > Share`

Then you'll be able to enter email addresses to share your preview with. Just had to go through that drudgery myself.

Comment: the Settings is grayed out - or it's just me ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that I found

```
ionic upload
```

to be a worthwhile CLI replacement for pushing new data up.